# Handling more than two conditions in Angular 8

Tags: angular

I am trying to replace an existing ternary operator condition in Angular 8 but getting an error with the promised call. It no longer recognizes it as a promise. I have tried to use if else condition since I have three conditions to check. when I hover over the first method, it shows promise but when I hover over the new method, it shoes type assignment values

Original method

```
public disapprove1 = (type: 'Reset' | 'Reject') => {
    const promise = type === 'Reset'
      ? this.service.reset(this.id, this.type, this.message)
      : this.service.reject(this.id, this.type, this.message);

    promise.then(() => {
      this.messageService.add(`Successfully ${type}.`, 'info');
      this.navigateToApprovalList();
    });
}
```

New method

```
public disapprove = (type: 'Reset' | 'Reject' | 'Approve' ) => {
    if ( type  === 'Reset') {
       this.service.reset(this.id, this.type, this.message);
    } else if (type === 'Reject') {
       this.service.reject(this.id, this.type, this.message);
    } else if (type === 'Approve') {
      this.service.approve(this.id, this.type, this.message);
    }
    const promise = type;

    promise.then(() => {
      this.messageService.add(`Successfully ${type}.`, 'info');
      this.navigateToApprovalList();
    });
  }
```

Comment: `const promise = type;`, but `type: 'Reset' | 'Reject' | 'Approve'` - why did you expect that to work?

Comment: The first method has const promise = type === 'Reset'

Comment: I'm not sure you understand the first method, then - `type === 'Reset'` is a *condition*, the actual value assigned to `promise` is the return value of whichever service method gets called - `foo = bar ? baz : quz` assigns either `baz` or `qux` to `foo`, not `bar`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator.

Comment: yes not that i am not using ternary how do implement promise with if else

Comment: You need to assign *the thing that's actually a promise* to the name `promise`. As before, that's the return value of a service method call. Note this isn't anything to do with Angular or TS, just basic JS logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to rewrite your code to:

```
public disapprove = (type: 'Reset' | 'Reject' | 'Approve' ) => {
  let promise;
  if ( type  === 'Reset') {
    promise = this.service.reset(this.id, this.type, this.message);
  } else if (type === 'Reject') {
    promise = this.service.reject(this.id, this.type, this.message);
  } else if (type === 'Approve') {
    promise = this.service.approve(this.id, this.type, this.message);
  }

  promise.then(() => {
    this.messageService.add(`Successfully ${type}.`, 'info');
    this.navigateToApprovalList();
  });
}
```

as already was commented here, you call `then()` on received argumnet of type `String`. You should call it on `Promise` instead